# Why does executing a simple command in a grouping command does not fork a subshell process, and the compound command will do it

Tags: linux, bash, shell, subshell

I know that grouping commands`(command-list)` creates a **subshell environment**, and each listed command is executed in that **subshell**. But if I execute **a simple command** in the grouping command, (use the `ps` command to output the processes), then **no subshell process is output**. But if I tried to execute a list of commands (**compound command**) in the grouping command, then **a subshell process is output**.  Why does it produce such a result?

- A test of executing a **simple command** (only a `ps` command) in a grouping command:

  ```
  [root@localhost ~]# (ps -f)
  ```

  with the following output:

  ```
  UID         PID   PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
  root       1625   1623  0 13:49 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
  root       1670   1625  0 15:05 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -f
  ```
- Another test of executing a **compound command**(a list of commands) in a grouping command:

  ```
  [root@localhost ~]# (ps -f;cd)
  ```

  with the following output:

  ```
  UID         PID   PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
  root       1625   1623  0 13:49 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
  root       1671   1625  0 15:05 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
  root       1672   1671  0 15:05 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -f
  ```

I tested a lot of other commands (compound commands and simple commands), but the results are the same. I guess even if I execute a simple command in a grouping command, `bash` should fork a subshell process, otherwise it can't execute the command. But why can't I see it?

Comment: Use `(echo $BASH_SUBSHELL)` to print subshell level and use `echo $BASHPID` (bash ver > 4) to print current process id of `bash`

Comment: To the basics I recommend this book: [Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment](https://www.amazon.de/Programming-Environment-Addison-Wesley-Professional-Computing/dp/0321637739)

Comment: Can you give me a clear explanation, thank you

Comment: Interestingly you don't see a subshell `bash` process when running `(ps -f & cd)` either. This makes me think it might be a timing issue.

Comment: More minimal demo of this curiosity:  `ps -o ppid=$(pidof ps)`, then with grouping `(ps -o ppid=$(pidof ps))`, then with grouping and an added `:` do-nothing command `(ps -o ppid=$(pidof ps) ;  :)`.  The first two output the same two numbers, the last outputs the same two and one more.

Comment: As Kamil Cuk and PSkocik said, it may be due to the optimization of bash that these unintended consequences are caused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash optimizes the execution. It detects that only one command is inside the `(` `)` group and calls `fork` + `exec` instead of `fork` + `fork` + `exec`. That's why you see one `bash` process less in the list of processes. It is easier to detect when using command that take more time `( sleep 5 )` to eliminate timing. Also, you may want to read [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41382/rule-for-invoking-subshell-in-bash) on unix.stackexchange.

I think the optimization is done somewhere inside `execute_cmd.c` in [`execute_in_subshell()`](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/execute_cmd.c#L1650) function (arrows `>` added by me):

```
 /* If this is a simple command, tell execute_disk_command that it
     might be able to get away without forking and simply exec.
>>>> This means things like ( sleep 10 ) will only cause one fork
     If we're timing the command or inverting its return value, however,
     we cannot do this optimization. */
```

and in [`execute_disk_command()`](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/execute_cmd.c#L5371) function we can also read:

```
/* If we can get away without forking and there are no pipes to deal with,
   don't bother to fork, just directly exec the command. */
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like an optimization and dash appears to be doing it too:

Running

```
bash -c '( sleep 3)' & sleep 0.2 && ps #or with dash
```

as does, more robustly:

```
strace -f -e trace=clone dash -c '(/bin/sleep)' 2>&1 |grep clone # 1 clone
```

shows that the subshell is skipped, but if there's post work to be done in the subshell after the child, the subshell is created:

```
strace -f -e trace=clone dash -c '(/bin/sleep; echo done)' 2>&1 |grep clone #2 clones
```

Zsh and ksh are taking it even one step further and for (when they see it's the last command in the script):

```
strace -f -e trace=clone ksh -c '(/bin/sleep; echo done)' 2>&1 |grep clone # 0 clones
```

they don't fork (=clone) at all, execing directly in the shell process.